# Таски luigi не видят конфиг файл

Tags: python, tornado

Использую luigi как ETL инструмент. Хочу передавать таскам значения параметров из конфиг файла ([как в примере](https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuration.html#parameters-from-config-ingestion)).

Конфиг файл в директории по умолчанию "папка проекта/etc/luigi/luigi.cfg". Использую venv. Пример таски:

```
improt luigi

class TestA(luigi.Task):
    x = luigi.Parameter(default=12)

    def run(self):
        print(f"Тестим x, x = {self.x}")
```

Пример конфига *luigi.cfg"

```
[TestA]
x=13
```

Запуск тасок происходит через `luigi.build([TestA()])`.
Справка

```
OS: Windows 10
Python: 3.8.5
luigi: 3.0.3.
```

Таски не видят параметров в конфиге, вообще конфиг не видно, он никуда не тянется.

Answer (score 0):

Сглупил, `etc\luigi\luigi.cfg` актуально для Linux

В windows файл нужно положить в корневую директорию проетка (это будет путь дял парсера по умолчанию)